# The encoding formula is $y=3x+21$ and it arrived at a decoding formula of $x=9y+19$ (using mod 26).

Tags: modular-arithmetic, cryptography

The encoding formula is $y=3x+21$ and it arrived at a decoding formula of $x=9y+19*$ (using mod 26).

I'm just confused on how they got the decoding formula/the inverse of the original equation? or how the x was isolated?

Comment: $3^{-1} = 9 \bmod 26$, can you find the rest?

Comment: $9y = 27x + 189 \implies 9y - 189 = 27x.$

Comment: $\!\bmod 26\!:\ y \equiv 3x\!+\!21 \iff 3x \equiv y\!-\!21\iff x \equiv y\color{#c00}{/3} - 7\equiv \color{#c00}9y-7\, $ by $\,\color{#c00}{1/3}\equiv 27/3\equiv \color{#c00}9,\,$ as explained in the linked dupe.

Answer (score -1):

Here is a simple way to show it:

Since $y=(3x+21) \mod 26$ you can equivalently write using identities of the remainders

$$3x=(y-21) \mod 26\Rightarrow 27x=(9y+19) \mod 26 $$

however since $27x=x+26x=x\mod 26$ the result follows.

More generally, to solve the equation $$px+qy=r\mod n,~ \gcd(p,n)=\gcd(q,n)=1$$

for $x$ or $y$ respectively, you need to find numbers $(a,b)$ such that

$$ap+bn=1$$

which is possible according to Bezout's identity, and one pair can always be found using the extended Euclidean algorithm. In our case, $p=3, n=26$ and the pair returned by the Euclidean algorithm is $a=9,b=-1$.

Comment: Please strive not to add more (dupe) answers to dupes of FAQs, cf. recent site policy announcement [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/33508/242).

Comment: @BillDubuque in this case we merge the questions in cryptography.se. Isn't this a good practice?